# Symfony Console 3 not showing any errors

Tags: php, symfony, console-application

I have a Symfony Console 3 application running fine using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Console\TimeCommand;

$application = new Application();

$application->run();
```

However, if I deliberate break the above code, I don't get any errors showing in the console, how can I get errors to be displayed?

Comment: Are you talking about introducing errors into TimeCommand? I tried your above file without the error reporting stuff.  If I change Application to something else I get the expected class not found message.  Otherwise just the normal console tool help screen.  The mere fact that you have a use TimeCommand statement is not going to trigger anything.

Comment: @Cerad Turns out that I do get errors with the error reporting in there (don't without).  However I was testing with "bad" code `fdas` (no semi colon) and don't get an error, however if I do `new Apple();` I get an error as expected

Comment: I noticed that if I do `die()` then I don't get any errors either.  Maybe this is just how the Symfony console behaves and I'm just too used to web apps.

Comment: Maybe because `Parse` errors don't show?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);`

Also check the [Symfony App Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html)

Comment: I was just getting started with this tutorial https://codeburst.io/build-a-php-console-application-using-symfony-692a876f416  I tried replacing `new Application` to `new AppKernal('dev', false);` to no avail?

Comment: I'm just using the Symfony Console component rather than the whole framework